# Bokeh: Display Additional Y-Axis Label with Multiple Y-Axis on the Same Side

Tags: python, graph, bokeh

I have a graph which is to display multiple lines, on 4 different y-axis scales. When I add a second y-axis to a side, only the label of the first axis is displayed. How can I have the 2nd axis label be shown?

Example:

```
from bokeh.models import Range1d, LinearAxis
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook

output_notebook()

fig = figure()

# Define x-axis
fig.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'

# Define 1st LHS y-axis
fig.yaxis.axis_label = 'Pressure [barg]'
fig.y_range = Range1d(start=0, end=200)

# Create 2nd LHS y-axis
fig.extra_y_ranges['temp'] = Range1d(start=0, end=50)
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='temp', axis_label='Temperature [°C]'), 'left')

# Create 1st RHS y-axis
fig.extra_y_ranges['lflow'] = Range1d(start=0, end=50000)
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='lflow', axis_label='Liquid Flowrate [bbl/day]'), 'right')

# Create 2nd RHS y-axis
fig.extra_y_ranges['gflow'] = Range1d(start=0, end=50)
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='gflow', axis_label='Gas Flowrate [MMscf/day]'), 'right')

fig.line(
    x = [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [80,88,87,70,77,82],
    legend = 'Pressure',
    color = 'purple'
)

fig.line(
    x = [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [5,6,5,5,5,4],
    legend = 'Temperature',
    y_range_name = 'temp',
    color = 'red'
)

fig.line(
    x = [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [10000,10100,10000,10150,9990,10000],
    legend = 'Liquid Flowrate',
    y_range_name = 'lflow',
    color = 'orange'
)


fig.line(
    x = [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [35,37,40,41,40,36],
    legend = 'Gas Flowrate',
    y_range_name = 'gflow',
    color = 'green'
)

fig.toolbar_location = 'above'

show(fig)
```

[image: Example Graph]

From the example above, only the Pressure and Liquid Flowrate axis labels are displayed. How can I make the Temperature and Gas Flowrate axis labels display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your bokeh version. I am currently using bokeh version 0.12.7 and your code without modifications and the result is as follows:
[image]

**For bokeh version 0.12.9** a workaround is to specify some large `min_border_left` and `min_border_right`, e.g.

```
fig = figure(plot_width=700,min_border_left=150,min_border_right=170)
```

The separation between the labels of the extra axes is larger than normal:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I'm using version 0.12.9

Comment: So I assume there has been a regression. This should be commented in the github repository https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh

Comment: @NixonInnes, adding min_border_left=150,min_border_right=170 made the labels appear on version 0.12.9, but the separation of label and axis is larger than normal. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks so much, its greatly appreciated.